# Why are unknown sites to which I don't link listed in Google Search Console's "Top linking sites" report?

Tags: google-search-console, links, backlinks

I checked my website on Google Console and I found something strange. I checked the links of my website in the console and in the box that shows Top linking sites. There are two link that when I open them on browser, there is nothing in the websites.  The sites are completely unknown for me.  Does any one know what are these and why my websites links to them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Stephen's answer not only will links to your site not hurt your seo, it will actually help.  You can use Google webmaster tools to submit your site to Google for indexing but what really helps your seo in the end are organic links.  It used to be that indexers relied on meta tags in your code but not anymore.  The number one thing that will increase your Google ranking is getting others to link your site.  If you look in your logs you will sometimes see referrer spam.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing.  Sometimes spammers and hackers will manipulate http headers to disguise what lead them to your website but for the most part you want to be linked.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems helpful. But I am still confused, Is this situation is that the one I should be worry about for being in risk of attacks?

Comment: Do you have Google webmaster tools set up?  If you are not tech savvy you can look at the traffic in Google webmaster tools and see if there is a clue.  If you are more technical you can look directly at the logs.  I don't mean to scare you with my talk of referrer spam, this is actually pretty common because blogs and cmses are actually pretty much constantly attacked and spammed so you have to be vigilant.  If you don't have Google webmaster tools I highly recommend getting it.  It will help you troubleshoot and help you improve your seo.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats very kind of you. Thanks for all your helps and time and everything. I will ask you for more help especially how to analyse traffics and logs , Yes I have webmaster tool. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Those are sites that link to your site, not sites to which you link.  If you click on the circled question mark, you can see Google's explanation:

[image]

> Links from outside your property to your property. Values are trimmed to root domain and grouped. If the current property is listed here, it is because the subdomain of the host page has been omitted. For example, if the link is from `www.example.com`, the value shown here would be `example.com`.

You can see exactly which pages link to your site and which pages they link to.

1. Clicking on the site.  It will take you to the "Top target pages" where you can see which pages on your site get the link. 
   [image]
2. Click on the page from your site.  It will take you to the "Top linking pages" report which shows you which pages on the external site link to your page.  
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. really helped. But I have a question. why a website that is down should link to my website and why google knows it? is there any way I can ask to detach the links?

Comment: A few links to your site won't hurt its SEO.